# Could I get data of instances when running test cases by Earlgrey

Tags: ios, ui-testing, earlgrey

I am newbie to UITest running by Earlgrey. I know the library which inherit from XCTestCase,so i though weather could get data of UI elements. But i don't find relative api to query info of instance in Earlgrey docs. Is it possible to reach it? Thanks to any advice?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by get data of UI elements? Do you want to extract data from a selected UI? If so, then you can use a custom action for it.

Comment: @khandpur Thanks ur response. For example, there is a tableview on the screen. Could i get the dataSource by click specific cell on the tableview?

Comment: You can write a custom action which accepts UITableView as the input. Then from there you can call any method to get the data source of the table view. To make sure you only match table views, use the correct matcher for the interaction.

Comment: Got it! Thanks,@khandpur. You save my day.

Comment: Happy to help! If you have any more questions feel free to join our slack channel: https://googleoss.slack.com/messages/earlgrey